# Hibernate not updating Boolean values

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception, boolean, mapping

I'm developing a small betting app with Spring and Hibernate and I got all methods from my tests running except one. The problem I have is when an admin in my app want to pick a bet option as a winner or loser. When a bet option is created, it's attribute to decide if is winner or not is set to null in database. So, i have a method in my service to pick this option as a winner (true) or loser (false). To acomplish this, I set the attribute as a Boolean type, so it can be null.

So, this is my class for an Option (simplified):

```
public class TypeOption {
    private Boolean isWinner;

    public TypeOption(double odd, String result, BetType type) {
        this.odd = odd;
        this.result = result;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Boolean getIsWinner() {
        return isWinner;
    }

    public void setIsWinner(Boolean isWinner) {
        this.isWinner = isWinner;
    }
}
```

My mapping to MySQL database is this:

```
CREATE TABLE TypeOption (
...
    isWinner BIT,
...
);
```

This is my service implementation:

```
public void changeOptionStatus(Long optionId, boolean status)
            throws InstanceNotFoundException {

    /* Find if the option exists, if not then throw an exception */
    typeOptionDao.find(optionId);

    typeOptionDao.changeOptionStatus(optionId, status);
}
```

And finally, this is my Dao implementation:

```
public void changeOptionStatus(Long optionId, Boolean status) {
    getSession().createQuery(
            "UPDATE TypeOption t" +
            " SET t.isWinner = :status" +
            " WHERE t.optionId = :optionId").
            setParameter("status", status).
            setParameter("optionId", optionId).
            executeUpdate();
}
```

My test method:

```
@Test
public void testPickWinner() 
        throws InstanceNotFoundException, TypeNotMultipleException {

    Calendar betDateAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
    betDateAfter.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

    CategoryInfo category = new CategoryInfo("categoria1");
    categoryInfoDao.save(category);

    EventInfo event = eventService.createEvent(
            new EventInfo("Barça-Madrid", betDateAfter, category));

    BetType type = new BetType("¿Who will win?", false, event);

    List<TypeOption> options = new ArrayList<TypeOption>();
    TypeOption option1 = new TypeOption(1.20, "Barcelona", type);
    options.add(option1);
    TypeOption option2 = new TypeOption(10, "Real Madrid", type);
    options.add(option2);

    eventService.addBetType(event.getEventId(), type, options);

    betService.changeOptionStatus(option1.getOptionId(), true);

    assertTrue(option1.getIsWinner());
}
```

When I call the method in the service from my test to pick an option as a winner or loser, I always get a NullPointerException, so it doesn't update it on database, but the SQL query is getting executed without errors.

This is the Stack Trace:

```
testPickWinner(es.udc.pa.pa015.practicapa.test.model.betservice.BetServiceTest) Time elapsed: 0.574 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at es.udc.pa.pa015.practicapa.test.model.betservice.BetServiceTest.testPickWinner(BetServiceTest.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Any idea on what's going here? I think I've mapped Boolean type in a wrong way or something like this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NPE is in BetServiceTest.testPickWinner. Looks like it is not DAO problem. Add test code.

Comment: Yes, the problem is in the test because I have an `AssertTrue(option.getWinner())` and it returns `NULL`. That's why it fails on NullPointerException. I'm adding my test code anyways.

Comment: In your test I can see `betService.changeOptionStatus(option1.getOptionId(), true);` and then immediately `assertTrue(option1.getIsWinner());` But I can't see code which is supposed to update isWinner flag in option1 instance. Probably you forget to reread option from DB

Comment: Yes, when I call ´betService.changeOptionStatus(option1.getOptionId(), true);´ it executes the method `changeOptionStatus` in my service and it calls the method `changeOptionStatus` in my DAO. I posted all of two methods code above so you can see them, thanks!